# bash regex (or test) strange behavior

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

```
[myuser@mycomputer]$ word="hello"
[myuser@mycomputer]$ if [[ $word =~ "^hello$" ]]; then echo "it was a hello"; else echo "must have been a goodbye"; fi
must have been a goodbye
```

I don't understand where is my error but I expected the opposite result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to dereference your variable, with `$`.

```
if [[ $word =~ "^hello$" ]]
      ^
```

Then, you must not enclose your string within double quotes `"` to be able to use the regular expressions.

```
if [[ $word =~ ^hello$ ]]
```

Comment: Can't it work without the dollar? Anyway, I tried with the dollar too and I got the same result.

Comment: I tried with and without the dollar. I'm going to edit my question to add the dollar.

Comment: According to `man bash` "An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3))." So the ^ and $ characters should be working.